# Comparing two directories and then removing mismatches (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, subdirectory, mismatch

Hello stackoverflow community! Help, already broke his head how to implement.

There are, for example, folders: 'D:\left' and 'C:\right'.

They contain the contents: files, directories with files, subdirectories, subdirectories with files. Most of the content is the same, but there may be 'extra' content in 'C:\right' (not matching the content of 'D:\left').

How can I compare the content (what is in) 'С:\right', what is not in 'D:\left' and after that (extra in 'С:\right') delete it so that the folders 'D:\left' and ' C:\right' became identical (in our case, we do not look at the size, time, etc. - purely by the names of their contents).

Tried like this to remove the excess:

```
difs = list(set(os.listdir('C:\right')) - set(os.listdir('D:\left')))
```

But this is not enough, because it does not propagate the effect to subdirectories.

Also like this:

```
from dirsync import sync
sync('D:\left', 'C:\right', 'diff')
```

But, there I am only interested in a small part of the output, and how exactly to put this output under deletion is simply not clear to me.

Delete everything from 'C:\right' to copy from 0 to 'D:\left' to 'C:\right' is not a solution.

I'm pretty sure the solution is fixated on:

```
os.walk
```

But I just can't line it up right :(

Many thanks in advance for any help and I apologize for the stupidity.

I'm attaching screenshots for clarity

Entrance:
[Entrance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxPfH.png)
[Entrance2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBppu.png)

Desired result after running the program:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMI5K.png)
[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycGto.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob):

```
from pathlib import Path

pl = Path(path/to/left)
pr = Path(path/to/right)

difference = (set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pr), pr.rglob('*'))) -
              set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pl), pl.rglob('*'))))
```

Here is an example:

```
right
  file1
  file5
  dir1
    file2
    file6
  dir2
    file3
    file7
    subdir1
      file4
      file8
    subdir2
      file9
    subdir3

left
  file1
  dir1
    file2
  dir2
    file3
    subdir1
      file4
```

```
>>> difference
{PosixPath('dir1/file6'),
 PosixPath('file5'),
 PosixPath('dir2/subdir3'),
 PosixPath('dir2/subdir2'),
 PosixPath('dir2/subdir1/file8'),
 PosixPath('dir2/subdir2/file9'),
 PosixPath('dir2/file7')}
```

Now you just need to delete all files and directories in `difference`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Riccardo Bucco very much for his reply. I did it and now it looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os

pl = Path(left_way) # left_way = r'D:\left' = 'D:\\left' 
pr = Path(right_way) 
difference = (set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pr), pr.rglob('*'))) - set(
        map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pl), pl.rglob('*')))) # RB genius move

if len(difference) > 0:
    print('\nContent to be deleted:\n')
        for a in difference:
            a2 = Path(pr, a)
            print('   ', a2)
        while True:
            copyornot = input('\nDelete? (Y/n):\n')
            if copyornot == 'Y':
                break
            elif copyornot == 'n':
                print('...')
                continue
            else:
                print('(Y/n)')
        for a in difference:
            a2 = Path(pr, a)
            if os.path.isfile(a2):
                os.remove(a2)
            if os.path.isdir(a2):
                shutil.rmtree(a2)
        print('\nShift is over, go drink beer')
```